# Can I use a VPN for remote access with private addresses

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, proxy

I have a local network that's configured with private IP addresses but I don't have NAT. I want to connect to a remote location using a VPN. Is this possible and if so, how do I do it and which technology should be used? How would it work exactly? I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not really provide enough information.

If your network can't reach the wider Internet then you can't use a VPN.

If it can, and you are using private addresses then it is has to be using NAT or a proxy.

If your stuff is using such a locked down proxy you should be speaking to the system administrator as you will get into trouble if you try and subvert it, but some VPN's can be configured (if you have control of both sides) to pretend to be a web server and web client and can work over port 80 or 443 - for example [OpenVPN](http://mediarealm.com.au/articles/2014/03/openvpn-client-through-a-restrictive-firewall-and-proxy/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remote desktop to the server over Internet?

Windows Remote Desktop will only work on local network, which means both RDP client and server need be on same local network.
To access Remote Desktop over the Internet, we’ll need to use a VPN to connect these two different networks. So the Windows Remote Desktop will work and act like on the same local network.

I found an article that how to setup a VPN and Access Windows Remote Desktop Over the Internet.
Due to the limited working environment, it is not available for me to test this. 
http://www.howtogeek.com/131961/how-to-access-windows-remote-desktop-over-the-internet/ 
After setup and connecting to VPN, please run the “ipconfig /all” command from an elevated CMD prompt to verify whether these RDP client and server are on the same subnet.
Please use the ”ping” command to test the communication between RDP client and server.